# where to use name/Id to get data from html using java script

Tags: javascript, html

I can't get data on a hidden tag by using javascript

enter code here

```
<html>
 <head>
   <script type="text/javascript">
    function validate()
    {
            var x = document.getElementByName("dd");
            document.getElementByName("hid").value= x;
            document.myform.submit();
    }
  </script>
 </head>
 <body>
    <input type="hidden" name="hid" value=""/>
    <button type="submit" name="dd" value="data" onClick="validate()"></button>
 </body>
</html>
```

I couldn't use the name to get data I need to know why and how to get data using javascript

Comment: If you need to reference form elements in JavaScript then it is preferable to give them an id rather than a name. The name attribute is used primarily for posting data.

Comment: It is also preferable to use onSubmit for the form and return true to allow the submission, rather than calling submit() explicitly.

Answer (score 2):

`getElementByName` does not exists as function in `Javascript`.

You have to use `document.getElementsByName` which  returns a **collection** of all elements in the document with the specified name (the value of the name attribute), as a **NodeList** object.

```
function validate()
{
        var x = document.getElementsByName("dd")[0];
        document.getElementsByName("hid")[0].value= x;
        document.myform.submit();
}
```

**Note**: The **NodeList** object represents a `collection` of nodes. The nodes can be accessed by `index` numbers.

Comment: That not was user asking for. The issue is with `getElementByName` function.

Comment: @31piy, only `input text` is hidden and you can set its value wherever you need. This is practice for instance when you submit a form but you don't want to display the `id` number in form, but you needed for server-side.